# how to make my webpage hosted on azure VM accessible (or live) on the internet

Tags: azure, iis, web-hosting

I have an azure virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 R2.

I used IIS to host my webpage on the server and set the binding to port 8080. I can browse to page from IIS (localhost:8080)

How can I access the page from outside the server? How can I make my webpage go live?

I am sure there are some networking and firewall settings involved. This is my first time using IIS to host anything, so I need guidance or steps to accomplish what I need.

I am trying to find articles online on how to tackle my problems but I am so new to all these things I am not sure what to look for.

And also, I have tried creating an Inbound Firewall rule on my server to allow any request to port 8080, which didnt help any.

Please give me suggestions or point me to some reading material to help me with my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add port 80 to the VM's NSG (if not in a VNET or DMZ topology) please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-compute-single-vm/ and  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-dmz-nsg-fw-udr-asm/

don't forget all other IIS rules still apply as you would have in a normal situation on premisse

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you techmike2kx. The first article help me with what I was needing. I created Network Security Group and added an Inbound Security Rule to allow request to port 8080. This will help me get started with what I am trying to do.

Comment: any time, upvoting the answer is always appreciated ;-)